# What's the JSON parser library used in Grails framework?

Tags: json, grails

I'm currently creating a standalone Java application. The logic is basically a ported version a Service class of another application (in Grails). In my standalone application, I used json-lib (http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/). After completing and testing my standalone app, I noticed that there is an issue with json-lib when parsing some input strings (i.e. it can't handle this {"source":, "another "quote inside" text"}). I believe in my Grails project, I didn't encounter that. I can't find a doc that says what JSON library was used in Grails framework. I would like to use that too.

I know I should post this question to Grails mailing list but would like to ask this here as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Grails uses the [converters plugin](http://www.grails.org/Converters+Plugin) some more info [here](http://grails.org/Converters%20Reference) which relies on the import:

import grails.converters.*

The grails converter obtains JSONObject and JSONArray from
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.*;

Therefore this library is groovy based, so it may not fit your needs in a java only project.

Comment: thanks for that information. however, i think i had another issue. i created a separate entry for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142121/can-a-malformed-json-string-be-parsed-successfully