# Can a malformed JSON string be parsed successfully?

Tags: java, json

Here's a sample string:

```
String s = "{\"source\": \"another \"quote inside\" text\"}";
```

What's the best way to parse this? I've already tried 4 parsers: **json-lib**, **json-simple**, **gson**, and **Grails built-in JSON parser**.

I'm using Java and I want to know if there's a way to fix the string after catching a MalformedJsonException or something.

Note: Or is this might be a bug in Twitter API? Here's a sample response string:

```
{
    "coordinates": null,
    "user": {
        "is_translator": false,
        "show_all_inline_media": false,
        "following": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
        "listed_count": 11,
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/a/1298064126/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
        "favourites_count": 4,
        "followers_count": 66,
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "statuses_count": 1078,
        "time_zone": "Tokyo",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "friends_count": 51,
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "id_str": "107723125",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "created_at": "Sat Jan 23 14:16:03 +0000 2010",
        "profile_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/652140488/--------------_normal.jpg",
        "description": "Mu8ecdu56e3u306eu56e3u9577u3068u30eau30fcu30c0u30fcu3067u3059u3002u8da3u5473u306fu7af6u99acu306eu4e88u60f3u3068u30b0u30e9u30c3u30d7u30eau30f3u30b0u3068u6253u6483u3092u30e1u30a4u30f3u3068u3057u3066u3044u307eu3059u3063uff01",
        "location": "u5bccu5c71u770c",
        "notifications": null,
        "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
        "protected": false,
        "screen_name": "mattsun0209",
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "lang": "ja",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "name": "u307eu3063u3064u3093",
        "verified": false,
        "id": 107723125,
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "utc_offset": 32400,
        "url": null
    },
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "text": "u3042u30fcu3001u7d50u819cu708eu306bu306au3063u3066u3057u307eu3063u305fu3002",
    "contributors": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "source": "u003Ca href="http: //twtr.jp" rel="nofollow"u003EKeitai Webu003C/au003E",
    "id_str": "42128197566861312",
    "created_at": "Mon Feb 28 07:45:19 +0000 2011",
    "geo": null,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": []
    },
    "truncated": false,
    "place": null,
    "id": 42128197566861312,
    "favorited": false
}
```

Take note of the `source` property:

```
"source": "u003Ca href="http: //twtr.jp" rel="nofollow"u003EKeitai Webu003C/au003E"
```

Comment: can you show the code where you are parsing.

Comment: @Suresh String s="{\"source\": \"another \"quote inside\" text\"}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
GsonVo obj2 = null;
try{
    obj2 = gson.fromJson(s, GsonVo.class);
}
catch(JsonSyntaxException e){
    logger.error(e, e);
}

logger.debug(obj2.text2);

Comment: edit your question and place this code.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid that's a classic "garbage in, garbage out" situation. The JSON is **invalid**, and so you can't parse it properly. You can only guess at what it's meant to be. Now, we humans can guess pretty well at what was intended (obviously), but that's much more difficult at a parser level.

If you know that consistently you're getting this invalid `source` property, you could pre-process the string before deserializing it, but the real fix has to be at the source of the invalid data — Twitter or whatever twit (as it were) is providing it. I'm assuming that this is the actual string data you've received, and not a processed form of it.

Comment: hmm.. so it is indeed an issue in Twitter API. hope they'll fix it soon. note that if the string is replaced with "{\"source\": \"another \\\"quote inside\\\" text\"}", it will be fine.

Comment: @firnnauriel: I'd strongly recommend telling Twitter of the problem. They can't fix what they don't know about. :-)

Comment: can't see their Submit Bug Report page or email address. feel free to do it, i'll give you the credit ;)

Comment: @firnnauriel: I have my own things to do, I'm afraid it's down to you.

Comment: Seems they have no public bugtracker, but there are some contact abilities: http://dev.twitter.com/discuss. Or you may want to twitter this page to them :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pre process the data before parsing it.

For each line, find the first colon (assumption: no colons in property names), then escape every double quote on the line except for the first after the colon and last on the line.

Comment: yes, that would be the solution if the format is like that but i'm getting a 'minified' version of the whole JSON string. now thinking how to replace only the source part..

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JSON grammar](http://www.json.org/), the format is invalid. Unless you work at Twitter, the only viable choice is to preprocess the response before parsing it.