# Permissive Netonsoft,Json parsing

Tags: json, parsing, json.net

I am trying to retrieve a permissive  dictionary using Newtonsoft.Json. Basically, what I the tool is doing is when it has an input like

```
string jsonText = 
@"{
    "key1" : "val1",
    "key2" : "val2",
    "inconsistency",
    "key3" : "val3"
  }";
```

However, the

```
JObject.Parse(jsonText);
```

command will throw me an JsonReaderException because my Json is incorrect.

I would like to have some kind of method

```
public JObject PermissiveParse(jsonText)
```

which will return a JObject with the 3 valid JTokens. (skip the invalid one)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm afraid that's a classic "garbage in, garbage out" situation. The
>   JSON is invalid, and so you can't parse it properly. You can only
>   guess at what it's meant to be. Now, we humans can guess pretty well
>   at what was intended (obviously), but that's much more difficult at a
>   parser level.
>
> If you know that consistently you're getting this invalid `jsonText`,
>   you could pre-process the string before deserializing it, but the real
>   fix has to be at the source of the invalid data.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142168/393487